# Testing a Flash Loan Smart Contract - Have some issues

Tags: blockchain, solidity, pragma, remix

I am making a smart contract as I'm still learning solidity and practicing. I wrote the code, and I am receiving this error on Remix:

```
contracts/flash.sol:8:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum definition.
address private wallet = 0x7e31a8ba5cF188fd39f9aaCF667E9dFE2311A882;
^-----^
```

This is all the code that I have right now:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/aave/aave-solidity/contracts/AAVE.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap-v2-core/contracts/interfaces/ISushiV2Pair.sol";

// Set the wallet address
address private wallet = 0x0000000000000000000000000;

// Set the contract addresses
address private aave = 0x7deB5e830be29F91E298ba5FF1356BB7fC8B8C9D; // AAVE contract address
address private uniswap = 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f; // Uniswap contract address
address private sushiswap = 0x6b3595068778dd592e39a122f4f5a5cf09c90fe2; // SushiSwap contract address

// Set the token addresses
address private eth = 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE; // ETH token address
address private ape = 0x27Dce1e12396F3a2B49E4FdD7a4C9d938E5e5F97; // APE token address

// Set the contract ABIs
AAVE aaveContract;
IUniswapV2Pair uniswapContract;
ISushiV2Pair sushiswapContract;

constructor() public {
    aaveContract = AAVE(aave);
    uniswapContract = IUniswapV2Pair(uniswap);
    sushiswapContract = ISushiV2Pair(sushiswap);
}

// Borrow 100 ETH from AAVE
function borrowFromAAVE() public {
    aaveContract.borrow(eth, 100 ether, wallet);
}

// Swap 20 ETH to APE on SushiSwap
function swapETHtoAPEonSushiSwap(uint amount) public {
    sushiswapContract.swap(amount ether, 10**18, ape, wallet, address(this));
}

// Swap 80 ETH to APE on Uniswap
function swapETHtoAPEonUniswap(uint amount) public {
    uniswapContract.swapETHForExactTokens(amount ether, 10**18, ape, wallet, address(this));
}

// Swap all APE to ETH on SushiSwap
function swapAPEtoETHonSushiSwap(uint amount) public {
    sushiswapContract.swap(amount, 10**18, eth, wallet, address(this));
}

// Pay back the loan to AAVE
function payBackLoanToAAVE() public {
    // First, check if the wallet has sufficient balance to pay back the loan
    require(wallet.balance >= aaveContract.borrowBalance(eth, wallet), "Insufficient balance to pay back the loan.");

    // Pay back the loan
    aaveContract.repayBorrow(eth, wallet);
}

// Keep the profit in the wallet
function keepProfitInWallet(uint amount) public {
    // First, check if the contract has sufficient balance to transfer the profit to the wallet
    require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Insufficient balance in the contract.");

    // Transfer the profit to the wallet
    wallet.transfer(amount);
}
```

what am I doing wrong?
The error is showing where Wallet, AAVE, Uniswap and Sushiswap are located.

I tried many things, it keeps showing me the same error, please let me know what the issue is to learn more as I am a beginner, much appreciated champs

Comment: The error message shows that the `address private wallet` is on the 8th line, and that it's missing an expression that is usually located on the 1st or 2nd line (pragma). Can you edit the question and post all lines before this `wallet` as well?

Comment: Yes sure, I will post all the code now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `contract` (similar to `class` in other OOP languages) in which you want the `wallet` property declared.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/aave/aave-solidity/contracts/AAVE.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap-v2-core/contracts/interfaces/ISushiV2Pair.sol";

contract MyContract {
  // Set the wallet address
  address private wallet = 0x0000000000000000000000000;

  // rest of your code
}
```